# Why must a variable be declared in a for loop initialization?

Tags: java

```java
int v = 0;

for (v; v<2; v++) {
    ...

}
```

Why is this not allowed in Java?

Why do we have to declare variable `v` in the for loop initialization?
I know it's not a statement if I do it like that but why doesn't Java allow the above?

Comment: we don't; `for(;;)`

Comment: `v` isn't allowed because it's not a statement: it's the same reason that you can't write `v;` by itself elsewhere.

Comment: You [do not need it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264403/why-must-a-variable-be-declared-in-a-for-loop-initialization/60264612#60264612) for an enhanced `for` loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `v` is declared prior to the loop, you should leave the first part of the for statement empty:

```
int v = 0;

for (; v < 2; v++) {
    ...
}
```

There's no meaning to just writing `v;`.

Answer (score 5):

Your loop declaration is valid if you remove the extraneous `v` in the declaration (assuming `v` was declared beforehand):

Change it to `for(; v < 2; v++)`

All three modifiers in the traditional `for` loop are optional in Java.

### Alternatives examples:

Below is the same as a `while (true)` loop:

```
for (;;) {

}
```

Adding extra increments:

```
int j = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++, j++) {

}
```

Adding extra conditions to terminate the loop:

```
int j = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < 10 || j < 10; k++, j++) {

}
```

Declaring multiple of the *same* type variable:

```
for (int k = 0, j = 0; k < 10 || j < 10; k++, j++) {

}
```

And obviously you can mix and match any of these as you want, completely leaving out whichever ones you want.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

> The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination; increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The three expressions of the for loop are optional

Means that you could create `for` loop and leave some of 3 expr empty. One of options is declare `int v` before loop:

```
int v = 0;
for(; v<2; v++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare a variable in the `ForInit`.

As others have pointed out, you can simply omit the `ForInit`; but you can also use a list of statement expressions there.

For example, you can create new class instances, invoke methods and assign/increment/decrement variables:

```
int v;
for (new String(), "".toString(), v = 0, v++;;);
```

(This example is nonsensical, but legal)

However, you cannot mix these statement expressions with local variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

int w =0;

int v;

for(v;v<2;v++){

}
 you have declared **v** prior the loop but you again used without any initialization.

if you use **w** which is already declared and initialized prior then there will be no issues.like below code,

for(;w<2;w++){

}